# Checking if a number fits between two numbers in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I was wondering if it's possible to check if a number fits between two numbers in Objective C. For example:

```
if (variable == 1-100) {
     //Do Something
}
```

I don't mean if the variable is equal to 1 minus 100. I want to know if the variable fits between 1 and 100. I understand this may not be possible but I'm interested to know so if it is possible.

Comment: Make sure to do some reasearch before asking questions :) This is pretty trivial and can be found faster than actually posting the quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code..

```
if(variable >= MINVALUE && variable <= MAXVALUE){
** Do your stuff here**
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C you can use this simple check:

```
if (variable >=1 && variable <= 100)
```

In Swift it's even easier:

```
if 1 ... 100 ~= variable
```

Answer (score 0):

If, by "the variable fits between 1 and 100" you mean "variable should be between 1 and 100, including 1 and 100" then it is pretty trivial:

```
if (variable >= 1 && variable <= 100) {
     //Do Someting
}
```

NB: The "&&" is the logical test operator AND commonly used in C, C++, Objective-C, Java...

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
if ( var >= 1 && var <= 100 ){ ... }
```

Comment: it should be an && operation instead !!

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer.